# Set Windows XP simple start menu via CMD/Registry

Tags: windows-xp, batch, start-menu

We're using temporary user accounts and when logging in, every time the classic start menu is restored.

The new two-column start menu is *not* blocked by policies. I can turn it on manually, but I want to do that automated:
I want to force the new two-column start menu in Windows XP via a batch file (e.g. I'd need a command line tool, a VB script or a registry edit which does this).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the batch script method but there is a simpler solution to what you are trying to achieve.

Every new user logging in, the template of user details (start menu, desktop properties, taskbar properties etc) are all copied from c:\Documents and Settings\Default User\
Make a new user, update the start menu settings. Go back to the folder and copy all the contents to the "Default user" folder and you should be good to go.

Refer to site below for more information on "Default user":
http://blog.foreignkid.net/2011/05/windows-profiles-default-user-or-all-users/

Comment: That would be a possible solution, but sadly I'm not the system administrator. E.g. I'm just a user which wants to set up its system correctly with one click after each log on.